# PathforResource issue with a .ics file, objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I´m just learning programming in Objective C and I got stuck with getting the information from a .ics file to appear on my tableview.

The tableview works fine. I´ve tried it with information stored directly to the NSArray. I get a detailed information view when clicking on the headers.

When i try to get the information from the .ics file I don´t even get the headers to appear. I just get a empty window.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "DetailedInformationView.h"


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize dataArray;
@synthesize ical;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

-(id)init{

 if (self = [super init]) {


  dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"timeedit" ofType:@"ics"];
  NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: path forKey:@"Calendar app"];

  [dataArray addObject:dict];

  NSLog(@"init");

  self.navigationItem.title = @"Calendar App";

 }

 return self;
}

-(NSMutableArray*)parseCalendarWithString:(NSString*)_file{

 //NSMutableArray *parse = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self count]];

}

-(NSMutableArray*)parseCalendarWithPath:(NSString*)_path{

 //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"timeedit" ofType:@"ics"];

 //NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithPath: path];


 //self.dataArray = [NSArray: dict ];



 //[dict release];

 //return ;
}

-(void)sortArray:(NSMutableArray*)_array by:(iCalSortBy)_by{

 //dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 //NSMutableArray *array = [[dataArray alloc]sortedArrayUsingSelector::@selector(compare:)];

 //self.dataArray = array;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

 [self init];

 //self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];

 //ical = [[iCalParser alloc] initWithPath:@"timeedit"];

 //self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

 //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"timeedit" ofType:@"ics"]; 
 //NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithPath: path]; 
 //self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict, nil];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

 [super viewDidLoad];
}


/*
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations.
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
 */


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 if(section == 0){
  return @"Monday";
 }
 else if (section == 1){
  return @"Tuesday";
 }
 else if (section == 2){
  return @"Wednesday";
 }
 else if (section == 3){
  return @"Thursday";
 }
 else if (section == 4){
  return @"Friday";
 }
 else if (section == 5){
  return @"Saturday";
 }
 else if (section == 6){
  return @"Sunday";
 }
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 NSDictionary *dict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
 NSArray *data = [dict objectForKey:@"Calendar App"];
    return [data count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

 // Configure the cell.
 NSDictionary *dict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
 NSArray *data = [dict objectForKey:@"Calendar App"];
 NSString *cellValue = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

 NSLog(@"Conf Cell");

 //cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dataArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];
 //cell.textLabel.text = [[ical libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"DTSTART"];


    return cell;
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 NSDictionary *dict = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
 NSArray *data = [dict objectForKey:@"Countries"];
 NSString *selectedrow = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  DetailedInformationView *detailView = [[DetailedInformationView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedInformationView" bundle:nil];
 detailView.selectedrow = selectedrow;
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
  [[detailView label] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
  [detailView release];
 detailView = nil;

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
 [dataArray release];
}


@end
```

Comment: Chris, most of your code is irrelevant to your problem or even commented, it is too difficult to read it through to find the problematic place. Put some effort into making your question readable so you'll get an answer much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess your problem is this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"timeedit" ofType:@"ics"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: path forKey:@"Calendar app"];
```

An iCal file (.ics) is not an xml file in property list format, which means this should return `nil`.  You should find a different way to read iCal files.

Comment: ok? how? I have no idea how to solve this... ...I´ve tried to google for a way but it doesn´t seem that anyone has done this...

Comment: I am trying to find how to create the ics file also but don't see how to do it have you have any luck???